# Trouble printing float64 value in C

Tags: c, types, floating-point, printf

I apologize for any misunderstanding here with data types or the way C operates (I am relatively new to learning still). Can someone explain to me why I am unable to get the desired output (see below)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define size         10

typedef unsigned int      Uint16;

typedef long double        float64;


Uint16 i;


float64 normalization = 0;

void main() {

  for (i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
     normalization = normalization + i;    // same as "normalization += i;"

     printf("\n --------");
     printf("\n normalization %f", normalization);

  }

  return;
}
```

The console output is the following:

```
 --------
 normalization 0.000000
 --------
 normalization -0.000000
 --------
 normalization -2.000000
 --------
 normalization -2.000000
 --------
 normalization -0.000000
 --------
 normalization -3105036184601417900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
 --------
 normalization -0.000000
 --------
 normalization -26815615859885194000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
 --------
 normalization -0.000000
 --------
 normalization -0.000000
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
normalization = 0
normalization = 1
normalization = 3
normalization = 6
normalization = 10
normalization = 15
// and so forth...
```

Comment: On many systems, `unsigned int` is not a 16-bit type but a 32-bit type.  On some (most 64-bit) systems, `long double` is a 128-bit type.  Your code — or at least the numbers assigned to your typedefs — is not portable.

Comment: Note that `void main()` is a non-standard return type for `main()`.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168) for exhaustive details.  Also, the variable `i` should not be global; it should be local to `main()`, or even to the `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`.  Similarly for `normalization`; that should be a variable local to `main()`.

Comment: Since the `%f` format (with appropriate type size modifiers) prints 6 decimal places, you won't get what you expect using it as simply as that.  You can request 0 decimal places with `%.0f` (with appropriate type size modifiers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `long double` cannot be printed with `%f`. Instead use `double`, which will work with the `printf` format specifier `%f`.

Alternatively, if you *really* want to use `long double`, you can use `%Lf` (case sensitive) to print it.

If you specifically want the output you specified without trailing zeros, you'll have to use `%g` (for `double`) or `%Lg` (for `long double`; case-sensitive).

Also note that `long double` is not always 64 bits wide, and `unsigned int` is not always 16 bits wide. A much better idea than using your `float64` and `Uint16` would be to simply use the types without `typedef`s, as you should not assume the widths of the types.

Comment: I appreciate the help! However, I am still receiving the same issue because changing `%f` to `%Lf` or `%lf` or `%g` or `%Lg` does not work. Can someone try to replicate the example I provided? It will help me understand if the issue is elsewhere in my project. Thank you all so much for the help! :)

Comment: @TonyPendleton It's `%Lf`. Note the lowercase `f` and the uppercase `L`.

Comment: @TonyPendleton How does it not work? If you have changed `long double` to `double` then you need to use `%f` or `%g`.

Comment: That's on me! Thank you. I forgot to change that. All I had to do was change `typedef long double        float64;` to `typedef double        float64;`

Comment: @TonyPendleton But, as noted in the answer, you really shouldn't be using these `typedef`s. They make assumptions about the variable sizes and make it unclear what types you're dealing with (which you apparently have noticed).

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is mismatching format specifier and argument type, leading to *undefined behavior*.

The format `%f` (as well as `%lf`) is for plain `double`, not `long double`.

For `long double` you need to use the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) prefix `L` for the format, as in `%Lf`:

```
printf("normalization %Lf\n", normalization);
```

---

On an unrelated note, please make it a habit to have *trailing* newlines in your output. Because output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) by default is *line* buffered, leading newline could lead to unexpected "missing" output.